# where to use 'case' statement in the following query?

Tags: sql, function, case

This is the problem statement given to me:

[image: 1]

```
create or replace function disp_player_name (play_id in number)  
return varchar is status_name varchar(100);  
begin  
select country into status_name from player where id=play_id;  
return status_name;  exception  
when no_data_found then status_name := 'No such country'  
return status_name;  
end;/
```

where should I use the 'case' to print the status as given in the problem statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely seems like homework, but right after your SELECT INTO.

```
create or replace function disp_player_name (play_id in number)  
return varchar is status_name varchar(100);  
begin  

select country into status_name from player where id=play_id;  

CASE
            WHEN status_name = 'India' THEN
                status_name := 'Player belongs to India';

END CASE;

return status_name;

exception  
when CASE_NOT_FOUND then status_name := 'No such country'  

return status_name;  
end;/
```